# Logging level is info, but only warnings are shown. Python logging

Tags: python, python-3.7

We have a little configuration class that can return a logger object (from `logging` module, not a custom one) with some special formatting. The logger level is 20 but nothing below warning gets printted. Is there any other parameter that can affect logging behaviour?. Below, a little execution of what I mean:

```
logger = config_object.make_logger()
logger.setLevel(10)

# Prints logger attrs
print(logger.name)
print(logger.disabled)
print(logger.filters)
print(logger.level)

# Logger behaviour seems not right
logger.critical(f'method critical')
logger.error(f'method error')
logger.warning(f'method warning')
logger.info(f'method info')
logger.debug(f'method debug')
```

The code above outputs the following:

```
__main__
False
[]
10
method critical
method error
method warning
```

If `logger.level` is 10, shouldn't it log all the way down to `debug`?

Comment: what logger object is that? self-written or from the logging module https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html ?

Comment: @PatrickArtner from loggig module. Edit question

Comment: Not reproducible... What is `config_object`?

Comment: @Tomerikoo config_object is just some app configuration. The method `make_logger` returns a logger object (from `logging` module) with some specific formatting options, so every developer should use this formatting, instead of a ad-hoc defined

Comment: @Tomerikoo. Actually the config class does the same as the one that you linked... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

From official [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#handlers) for logging handlers:

> The `setLevel()` method, just as in `logger` objects, specifies the lowest severity that will be dispatched to the appropriate destination. **Why are there two `setLevel()` methods**? The level set in the logger determines which severity of messages it will pass to its handlers. The level set in each handler determines which messages that handler will send on.